# Easily Acces dynamicaly created Labels

Tags: vb.net

In my program I need to create some labels.
Howe ever the count of labels depends greatly on the a number of configurations files.

The labels are based on what kind of PLC module is loaded and how many. Each PLC Module (input module) has a different I/O address. The only constant here is that each I/O address is 1 word long (16bit).

For example if I have loaded 64 input module which is 4 words than the labels that need to be created are:

- 0.00 ...0.15
- 1.00 ...1.15
- 2.00 ...2.15
- 3.00 ...3.15

Each Label gets a name like:

OnOff_000 ... OnOff_015 and so on.

But now comes the tricky part for me, each label is initialized with a default backcolor = color.lightblue.
The backcolor of each label needs to be changes depending on the input state green(ON) and red(OFF).

I have managed to change the backcolor of one label with the following code:

```
Dim test As Label = CType(IO_ScanPanel.Controls("OnOff_000"), Label)
        test.BackColor = Color.Red
```

But how can I do this easily with all other labels

The labels are created with the following code:

```
Private Function InsertControls_InputsLabels(ByVal StartAdrs As Integer, ByVal EndAdrs As Integer, ByVal LocX As Integer, ByVal LocY As Integer) As String()
    Dim NumberOfElements As Integer = 0
    Dim Coordinates(1) As String

    Do Until StartAdrs > EndAdrs

        Do Until NumberOfElements > 15
            Dim On_OffInput As Label = New Label()

            On_OffInput.AutoSize = False
            On_OffInput.Size = New Size(36, 15)
            On_OffInput.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            On_OffInput.Location = New Point(LocX, LocY)
            If NumberOfElements < 10 Then
                On_OffInput.Text = StartAdrs & ".0" & NumberOfElements
                On_OffInput.Name = "OnOff_" & StartAdrs & "0" & NumberOfElements
            Else
                On_OffInput.Text = StartAdrs & "." & NumberOfElements
                On_OffInput.Name = "OnOff_" & StartAdrs & NumberOfElements
            End If

            On_OffInput.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            On_OffInput.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

            IO_ScanPanel.Controls.Add(On_OffInput)

            LocX = LocX + 32
            NumberOfElements = NumberOfElements + 1



        Loop
        NumberOfElements = 0
        LocY = LocY + 25
        LocX = 7
        StartAdrs = StartAdrs + 1

    Loop

    Coordinates(0) = LocX
    Coordinates(1) = LocY

    Return Coordinates

End Function
```

I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hold onto a reference to them by storing them in a List or maybe a Dictionary where the key is something like one of those addresses

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the BackColor property of every label, you can iterate the form's control collection as follows:

```
For Each myControl As Control In Me.Controls
   If TypeOf(myControl) Is Label Then myControl.BackColor = Color.Red
Next
```

The suggestion of @Plutonix is also a good one. Add each label to a list with form level scope as follows. I'd also recommend coding with Option Strict On and avoid implicit typecasting. I have made some changes on this basis.

```
Private myLabels As New List(Of Label)

Private Function InsertControls_InputsLabels(ByVal StartAdrs As Integer, ByVal EndAdrs As Integer, ByVal LocX As Integer, ByVal LocY As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim NumberOfElements As Integer
    Dim Coordinates(1) As Integer

    Do Until StartAdrs > EndAdrs
        Do Until NumberOfElements > 15
            Dim On_OffInput As New Label

            On_OffInput.AutoSize = False
            On_OffInput.Size = New Size(36, 15)
            On_OffInput.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            On_OffInput.Location = New Point(LocX, LocY)

            If NumberOfElements < 10 Then
                On_OffInput.Text = StartAdrs & ".0" & NumberOfElements
                On_OffInput.Name = "OnOff_" & StartAdrs & "0" & NumberOfElements
            Else
                On_OffInput.Text = StartAdrs & "." & NumberOfElements
                On_OffInput.Name = "OnOff_" & StartAdrs & NumberOfElements
            End If

            On_OffInput.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            On_OffInput.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

            Me.Controls.Add(On_OffInput)
            myLabels.Add(On_OffInput)
            LocX = LocX + 32
            NumberOfElements = NumberOfElements + 1
        Loop

        NumberOfElements = 0
        LocY = LocY + 25
        LocX = 7
        StartAdrs = StartAdrs + 1
    Loop

    Coordinates(0) = LocX
    Coordinates(1) = LocY

    Return Coordinates
End Function
```

The labels' BackColor property can then be updated as follows:

```
For Each myLabel As Label In myLabels 
   myLabel.BackColor = Color.Red
Next
```